# How to create multiple IP Addresses on a bonded interface with Netplan?

Tags: networking, 18.04, netplan, network-bonding

Edit: This may not be possible. According to the [Netplan Docs](https://netplan.io/examples/), aliasing cannot be implemented. If it can't, I suppose I will need to come up with another solution (e.g. use the old interfaces method).

Edit 2: Without using `netplan try`, and just `netplan apply`, I'm able to have multiple IP addresses with the same bonded interface (see config below). I will answer my question now.

I am trying to implement a netplan setup with something similar to this old `/etc/network/interfaces` setup:

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:56:78:90:12  
          inet addr:192.168.66.120  Bcast:192.168.127.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          inet6 addr: 1234:1234:1234:1234/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:121492924671 errors:0 dropped:4395640 overruns:0 frame:3517
          TX packets:80073661297 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:112218751342378 (112.2 TB)  TX bytes:26536012742300 (26.5 TB)
          Interrupt:16 

em1:1     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:56:78:90:12  
          inet addr:192.168.67.120  Bcast:192.168.127.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 

em1:2     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:56:78:90:12  
          inet addr:192.168.67.121  Bcast:192.168.127.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 

em1:3     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:56:78:90:12  
          inet addr:192.168.67.122  Bcast:192.168.127.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 

em1:4     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:56:78:90:12  
          inet addr:192.168.67.123  Bcast:192.168.127.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16 

em1:5     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 12:34:56:78:90:12  
          inet addr:192.168.67.124  Bcast:192.168.127.255  Mask:255.255.192.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Interrupt:16
```

However, it appears my syntax is wrong. I have 2 nics on a server, and I'm trying to create multiple IP Addresses on the bond. However, when I use `netplan try`, it tells me:

`bond0: reverting custom parameters for bridges and bonds is not supported`

```
network:
    bonds:
        bond0:
            addresses: 
            - 192.168.66.121/18
            - 192.168.67.125/18
            - 192.168.67.126/18
            - 192.168.67.127/18
            - 192.168.67.128/18
            - 192.168.67.129/18
            gateway4: 192.168.64.1
            interfaces:
            - eno1
            - eno2
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.3.222
                - 192.168.70.80
            parameters:
                mode: active-backup
                mii-monitor-interval: 100
    ethernets:
        eno1: {}
        eno2: {}
    version: 2
```

Where should the other IP Addresses be placed if it's bonded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config is working. I did not use aliases. Instead, I just used individual IP addresses, created a test firewall policy, and all is well it seems.

Here is the working config:

```
network:
    bonds:
        bond0:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.66.121/18
            - 192.168.67.125/18
            - 192.168.67.126/18
            - 192.168.67.127/18
            - 192.168.67.128/18
            - 192.168.67.129/18
            gateway4: 192.168.64.1
            interfaces:
            - eno1
            - eno2
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 192.168.3.222
                - 192.168.70.80
            parameters:
                mode: active-backup
                primary: eno1
                mii-monitor-interval: 100
    ethernets:
        eno1: {}
        eno2: {}
    version: 2
    renderer: networkd
```

Comment: How does ip -4 a looks now? or ifconfig -a ?